# Overwrite message in telegrambot with InlineKeyboardButton(Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, telegram-bot

I use the library [kotlin-telegram-bot](https://github.com/kotlin-telegram-bot)
How can I do overwrite a message from the bot. For example when the `InlineButton` is pressed, message from bot change on another text and change all buttons. I added a picture for clarity

[image]

I need to use message updates from telegram API and callback or there are simpler solutions?

*Update*
For example, I have some func, which generate 40+ buttons(now 41, get from GET request and parse into List)

```
fun generateButtons(buildList: List<String>?): List<Any> {
    val myNames: List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> = buildList!!.map {
        InlineKeyboardButton(text = it, callbackData = it)
    }.chunked(3)
    return myNames
}
```

After, I click on the button, delete current keyboard and return next inline keyboard

```
callbackQuery("some callback data") { bot, update ->
                update.callbackQuery?.let {
                    val chatId = it.message?.chat?.id ?: return@callbackQuery
                    val messageId: Long = it.message!!.messageId
                    nameButton = update.callbackQuery!!.data
                    bot.deleteMessage(chatId, messageId)
                    val inlineKeyboardMarkup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(generateButtonsParams())
                    bot.sendMessage(chatId = chatId, text = "asdasd", replyMarkup = inlineKeyboardMarkup)
                }
            }
```

I don't know how to make one callbackQuery for my 41 buttons and get data from clicked button

Comment: Could you please tell a bit about what you tried, and perhaps share the relevant code if any

Comment: @RohdeFischer 
I updated my question, added code, hopefully it became clearer ;)